# Why wont my Docker app display on my local server?

Tags: php, docker, containers

I've created a Docker app in the terminal and I'm trying to view it on my localhost machine but its not appearing. I've assigned a 80:80 port to it and when i run Docker ps it shows that the container is running, but its not appearing on the web browser. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

DockerFile

```
FROM php:7.2-apache 
COPY src/ /var/www/html/
```

Wordcountapp.php

```
<?php

$paragraph = $_REQUEST['paragraph'];

 ?>

<html>

<title>Count number of words in a paragraph</title>
<body>
<form action="wordcountapp.php" method="post">
  <input type ='text' name = "paragraph" value ="Enter text..."/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
Total word count : <?php echo str_word_count($paragraph);?>
</body>
</html>
```

Running in terminal

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                               NAMES
da4b13872a9a   Appwordcount   "docker-php-entrypoi…"   4 seconds ago   Up 2 seconds   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp   my-app
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: when type into my browser 127.0.0.1:80 it doesn't appear. The apache "it works" page appears instead?@anemyte

Comment: Have you tried with the name of the file - 127.0.0.1:80/Wordcountapp.php?

Comment: What's your host OS, and what "flavor" of Docker are you using?  (Are you using Docker Machine or the older Docker Toolbox setup; or are you on a native Linux system; or are you using the Docker Desktop application?)